# same 8bit created surface resulting in a different pitch value

Tags: c++, sdl2

Given:

```
const int w = 10;
const int h = 10;
const int d = 8;
uint8_t* pixels = new uint8_t[w * h]

SDL_Surface* src = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(pixels, w, h, d, w, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SDL_Surface* dst = SDL_ConvertSurface(src, src->format, 0);
// src->pitch == 10;
// dst->pitch == 12;
//std:: cout << src->pitch == dst->pitch << std::endl;
```

My expected result is that the two pitches must match.

In this case I have the "weird" 12 pitch value for the `dst` image create from the `src`.

- Is that due to memory alignment optimization?
- Is there any reasonable explanation about it?
- Are those padding bytes used somehow or just wasted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is based on a quick look at the SDL source code for `SDL_ConvertSurface`:

`SDL_ConvertSurface` calls `SDL_CreateRGBSurface`, which determines the used pitch with `SDL_CalculatePitch`, which aims to pad the surface to 4-bytes for speed reasons. This makes sense as memory is likely to be fetched in minimum 32-bit chunks (at least on x86).

So yes, this is indeed a memory alignment optimization (12 is padded to 4, 10 is not). The extra allocated bytes don't seem to be used, as they are allocated to be part of the surface's pixel array.

Comment: yes i was starting looking at the source code too! :)
So basically it is not completely neither correct how i did in the first create surface.
(or potentially as well SDL should realloc in memory alignement from the pointer)
thanks

Comment: Yeah, all though a better idea is to forget about the optimizations that are required for efficient CPU-side rendering and just switch to SDL_Textures if possible.